# OWASP top ten attacks and Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, owasp

I am evaluating security for my web application. As I am using Spring in my web application I would like to leverage the Spring Security framework. I searched for more info about web security and come across OWASP community and it's top 10 attacks list. So my question is; would it be suffice to configure Spring Security to secure my application? What all security threats out of OWASP top 10 (2013) are handled by Spring Security Framework?

Comment: Spring Security only handles securing URLs and gives you a login framework, if the underlying authentication mechanism is still weak, you'll still have a potential security breach. Spring Security does provide a mechanism to force SSL on URLs, but then you still need an SSL certificate. So in short, Spring Security is not enough to to satisfy the OWASP top 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building secure applications is a challenging task and there is no "silver bullet" product which would make the application automatically secure for you. Therefore the simple usage of Spring Security certainly does not automatically mean that your application is secure! Spring Security is a great tool which helps with many aspects of building of secure applications, but like with any tool you need to know how to use it properly.

Spring Security can help you address at least the following OWASP TOP10 issues:

- *A2-Broken Authentication and Session Management* - by providing mechanisms for efficient and secure authentication and session management
- *A4-Insecure Direct Object References* - by providing mechanisms for authorization within application
- *A6-Sensitive Data Exposure* - Spring Security's crypto module provides necessary cryptography capabilities
- *A7-Missing Function Level Access Control* - by providing means for authorization in UI and server side
- *A8-Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)* - by providing support for generation and validation of tokens mitigating CSRF attacks

Answer (score 9):

I advise to use a layered security architecture. I mean, it’s possible to create a secure application by hand but it’s extremely difficult to implement. Some security features such
as authentication and basic access control (url level or GUI component level) are relatively easy to implement but requirements such as instance level security (specially working with legacy databases), Sql Injection and XSS are harder.

I recommend to use Spring Security and implementing as much as possible custom validations. In addition to that I recommend to use [HDIV](http://www.hdiv.org) in order to add an extra security layer that could
help to avoid the exploitation of risks not covered by custom validations. Specifically the features offered by HDIV are:

- **A1- Injection**: regarding HTTP parameters’ values and urls HDIV reduce the risk of this vulnerability to only the data that come from text fields within forms, applying integrity validations (assures the received value is the same as the generated at server side) for the rest of the data that come from client side. For text fields included within forms, HDIV offers generic validations (whitelist and blacklist) in order to avoid injection attacks injection attacks.
- **A2-Broken Authentication and Session Management**: HDIV doesn’t offer functionalities for 
  this web risk.
- **A3-XSS**: the same as A1 but in that case to avoid XSS risks.
- **A4-Insecure Direct Object References**:    HDIV controls all the data
  generated at server side ensuring the    integrity of the data and
  avoiding this vulnerability.
- **A5-Security misconfiguration**: HDIV doesn’t include specific functionalities for    that but doesn’t allow the access to resources not sent by the server    previously, avoiding the exploitation of unexpected behaviors or access to private resources.
- **A6-Sensitive Data Exposure**: HDIV    offers confidentiality feature to
  hide the values of HTTP parameters.
- **A7-Missing Function Level Access Control** : thanks to the integrity validations implemented
  by HDIV, avoids the exploitation of this vulnerability and limit the user to execute legal actions and maintaining the original contract (GUI or API) offered by the
  application.
- **A8-Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)**: HDIV adds aleatory tokens to
  avoid this vulnerability
- **A9-Using components with known vulnerabilities**: HDIV doesn’t include
  specific functionalities for that but thanks to the interaction
  limitations applied to    the user in many cases is not possible to
  exploit the    vulnerability.
- **A10-Unvalidated redirects and forwards**: This    vulnerability is
  mainly related to the manipulation of non editable    data or data
  generated previously at server side. HDIV controls all    the data
  sent by the server and doesn't allow the redirection to    malicious
  web sites.

In addition to these functionalities to protect from OWASP top ten web risks, HDIV generates also logs related to the malicious activity or attacks against your web site including all the information about the attack and the username within authenticated web sites.

Regards,

Roberto Velasco (HDIV team)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [HDIV](http://hdiv.org/) which has support for multiple frameworks.